# Eclipse CDT not building fresh project of certain name

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've a C++ project in Eclipse CDT called `agos` with about 50 source files. The problem is that it doesn't build anymore. Eclipse reports that it built:

```
15:23:28 **** Build of configuration Debug for project agos ****
make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

15:23:28 Build Finished (took 59ms)
```

However, the built time is way too short and there are no `.o` files and no executable anywhere under the project directory after building.

To rebuild, I've tried this:

1.)

- have switched on `Build Automatically`
- choose `Project > Clean...`
- result: only clean is reported; build is not done and not reported

2.)

- switch off `Build Automatically`
- choose `Project > Clean...` (and have `Start a build immediately` ticked)
- result: build is reported as above, but not done

3.)

- keep `Build Automatically` switched off
- choose `Project > Clean...` (and have `Start a build immediately` unticked)
- choose `Project > Build Project`
- result: build is reported as above, but not done

Now the mysterious thing: Another project with the same content compiles fine:

When I create another C++ project (let's call it `foo`) and copy 
all source files from `agos` to `foo`, then `foo` builds just fine. When I delete `agos` and all its files on disk (I've checked that they the project folder gets deleted), restart Eclipse, and create `agos` again and copy all the files back from `foo` to `agos`, then `agos` still doesn't build and `foo` still builds fine.

I'm using
- Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit)
- Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
- Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0), Build id: 20150621-1200

I have kept Eclipse CDT as the bundle is after download and I did not install any additional plugins.